# Non-competition clauses in ReactJS?

Tags: reactjs, facebook, react-native

I'd like to use ReactJS and React Native to develop a web & mobile application to help connect filmmakers in a social network, but I've heard that Facebook's legal team shuts down React projects that might compete with Facebook.

Has anyone had an experience with Facebook's legal team regarding React non-competition clauses?

Do they actually revoke developer access to React if a project might compete with Facebook, or is this just a common myth?

Some Balsamiq sketches of the prototype, if that helps: https://photos.app.goo.gl/cN63uin62rMvhpJE7

Comment: This question seems to be off topic.

Comment: react can be installed via npm. how would they revoke access to that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://code.fb.com/web/relicensing-react-jest-flow-and-immutable-js/ will solve your question about licensing